# Преобразовать список таким образом, чтобы сначала располагались все элементы, равные нулю, а потом - все остальные

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#define n 5
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int i;
  int val;

  struct Mas{
    int num;
    struct Mas *next;
  }start, *node;

  start.next = NULL;
  node =&start;
  for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    node->next =(struct Mas *)malloc(sizeof(struct Mas));
    node = node->next;
    printf("\nVvedite chislo = ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    node->num = val;
    node->next = NULL;
  }
  node = start.next;
  while(node){
    printf(" %d ", node->num);
    node=node->next;
  }

  // Миннимальный Элемент
  node = start.next;
  int min=7000;
  for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
    if(node->num < min)
      min = node->num;
      node=node->next;

  }
  printf("\n Min = %d", min);
  // Сумма между первым и последним положительным элементом

  int pos1;
  int pos2;
  int sum = 0;
  node = start.next;
  Mas *node2;
  Mas *node3;
  while(node){
    if(node->num > 0){
      node=node->next;
      node2 = node;
      break;
    }
  node=node->next;
  }
  while(node){
      if(node->num > 0)
      break;
      sum += node->num;
      node=node->next;
  }
    printf("\nSum = %d", sum);
    // Преобразовать список таким образом, чтобы сначала располагались все элементы, равные нулю, а потом - все остальные.
    // int count = 0;
    // node=start.next
    // while(node){
    //   if(node.num == 0)
    // 
    // }
    // node=node->next;
    // //
    // // if
    // 
    // 
    // 
    // }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Помогите реализовать, логику понимаю, а как записать в коде не очень. Поидее найдем ноль, затем переставим его в начало списка, при этом сместив все остальные данные и так со всеми нулями.

Comment: Выберите какой-нибудь один язык: - либо C, либо C++ - и соответственно скорректируйте свой код.

Comment: @Rulz, идея в целом верная. Лучше реализовывать как 2 шага -- 1) удалить элемент с нулем из списка (лучше смотреть *на следующий*, будет проще в реализации); 2) вставить его в начало списка.

Comment: Что-то вроде такого -- `for (p = list; p && p->next;) {
       if (p->next->num == 0) {
           q = p->next;
    p->next = q->next;
    q->next = list;
    list = q;
       } else 
           p = p->next;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Слышком сложно вам  помогать с вашим кодом(ответ будет слышком обьемным). Лучше смотрите как делать на `C++`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main()
{        
    std::list<int> nodes(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                         std::istream_iterator<int>());
    std::partition(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), [](int i) { return i == 0; });
    for (int i : nodes)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    return 0;   
}
```

Первая строчка сразу инициализирут список с консоли, вторая выпоняет задачу, третья выводит на консоль

Comment: Попробовал, выдает ошибку в терминал. Не до конца понял программу.

Comment: `#include <iterator>` забыли